# Showing the proportions of values across each column in a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have created the following DataFrame:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(5, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
```

Now I wish to show the proportion of each value (0,1,2) across each column. Ideally I'd like to represent this as a stacked bar chart - Column names on the x axis (so 8 bars in total from A to H), with the different colours on the bars representing the proportion of each value (0,1,2).

What's the easiest/simplest/most concise way to do this?

Edit: I've found an easy way to represent the proportions - not as a bar char, but as a DataFrame. See below:

```
df = pd.concat([dataset['A'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100),
               dataset['B'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100),
               dataset['C'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100),
                dataset['D'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100),
               dataset['E'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100),
               dataset['F'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100),
               dataset['G'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100),
               dataset['H'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)],
               axis=1,keys=('proportions A','proportions B',
                           'proportions C', 'proportions D',
                           'proportions E', 'proportions F',
                           'proportions G', 'proportions H'))
```

However, is there a more concise way to code this? E.g. anyway to make the above code into a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the most efficient way. In terms of shortening it, is it this what you are looking for? It is really your solution, just condensed via comprehensions.

```
df = pd.concat([dataset[colid].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100) for colid in list('ABCDEFGH')],
              axis=1,keys=('proportions ' + colid for colid in list('ABCDEFGH')))

print(df)
```

which results in

```
   proportions A  proportions B  proportions C  proportions D  proportions E  \
0            NaN           20.0            NaN           60.0           20.0   
1           80.0           40.0           40.0           20.0           40.0   
2           20.0           40.0           60.0           20.0           40.0   

   proportions F  proportions G  proportions H  
0           20.0           40.0           80.0  
1           40.0           40.0           20.0  
2           40.0           20.0            NaN
```